# Issue with Header partial in EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

New to node/express and unable to find a SO answer similar to what I'm facing. I have an Express app using `partials/header` for navbar across all pages, but I'm running into an issue where if I go to a location like `/user/:username` it is not rendering the header with the correct styling.

This is what it looks like on all pages that are just `/{something}`:

[image]

And this is what is looks like if I go to `/user/:username` or any other url with a param:

[image]

Notice the reduced padding and nav-link changes. I'm using ejs for the viewengine with styling from Bootstrap, this is my **app.js** setting the viewengine and path to views:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

**header import that works on all other pages**:

```
<%- include('partials/header'); -%>
```

**user.ejs render from second screenshot:**
`app.get('/user/:username', (req, res) => res.render('user'));`

If I change this to just `/user` (removing the parameter entirely) it renders out the navbar just fine which has me confused on why the request parameter would be causing a conflict like this. I tried moving the header file from views/partials to just views + updating the include statements but that did not change anything. I also tried in a separate browser (Chrome) from my main I use for development (Firefox) but no luck there either.

Answer (score 0):

Realized my issue right after posting...and also can't believe I lost 2 hours to a missing slash.

In my `partials/header` I still had my own styles.css referenced by:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`

when it needed to be:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">`